# Pass args to the Dockerfile from docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the next configuration of my prod env:

**docker-compose-prod.yml**

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  nginx:
    build:
      context: nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      args:
        LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN: ${LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN}
    container_name: nginx   
    networks:
      - app-network
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY production/* /etc/nginx/conf.d/

ARG LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN
RUN sed -i s/{LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN}/${LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN}/g /etc/nginx/conf.d/landing.conf

EXPOSE 80 443
```

So when I try do build it I got next warning:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml build --build-arg LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN="test.com" nginx
```

> WARNING: The LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN variable is not set. Defaulting to a
>   blank string.

Where I made a mistake?

Comment: add the ARG value aslo in your Dockerfile `ARG LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN $LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN`or export it before start building

Comment: I got compose warning message before building from Dockerfile, seems like **--build-arg** doesn't see my input

Answer (score 15):

the key word `ARG` has a different scope before and after the `FROM` instruction

Try using ARG twice in your Dockerfile, and/or you can try the ENV variables

```
ARG LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN
FROM nginx:alpine

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY production/* /etc/nginx/conf.d/

ARG LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN
ENV LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN=${LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN}

RUN sed -i s/{LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN}/${LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN}/g /etc/nginx/conf.d/landing.conf

EXPOSE 80 443
```

Comment: "the key word ARG has a different scope before and after the FROM instruction" - that hit the nail for me, thank you! Did not find it in the documentation.

Comment: Un-effing-believable. This cost me 4 hours of my life.

Comment: @Spyros maybe you would like to try something like sonarcloud, because I realised that it is not gonna behave like it should when [my VSCode extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SonarSource.sonarlint-vscode) showed me some yellow lines under them suggesting that they are not used correctly.

Answer (score 8):

There are 2 options how to make it work:

1. Use existing code in `docker-compose-prod.yml` and set environment
   variable `LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN`:

   `export LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN=test.com`

   then run build step w/o passing the build args:

   `docker-compose -f docker-compose.production.yml build nginx`
2. Comment / delete 2 lines from `docker-compose-prod.yml` file:

```
        args:
          LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN: ${LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN}
```

Then you'll be able to build it with passing arguments at build time:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml build --build-arg
LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN="test.com" nginx
```

The reason why it currently doesn't work is because those 2 lines in `docker-compose-prod.yml` file explicitly sets the `LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN` argument to be populated by `${LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN}` environment variable.

And when you run `docker-compose build` with `--build-arg` option it doesn't set any env vars but literally passes arguments for `build` step.

Comment: While your answer is nice,  it are IMHO possible creative work arounds and does not answer the question, @Nathanael has provided the real answer. so that's why you get (non personal) down vote from me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ARG LANDING_PAGE_DOMAIN=value` to your Dockerfile:

From the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)

> The ARG instruction lets Dockerfile authors define values that users
>   can set at build-time using the --build-arg flag