# Docker env. Synonyms for variables in env file?

Tags: docker, environment

Let suppose I have an env file with

```
DB_PW=123
```

And a docker command that expects

```
-env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=123
```

Is there a way to take that DB_PW from the env file and assign it to MYSL_ROOT_PASSWORD in the command line? (obviously not having to add a line to the env file with the explicit assignment)
I have been reading here and there, but I am not sure if it's possible or where this would be documented.

Comment: Have you seen this post how you can Pass arguments from docker-compose to the docker file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58695423/pass-args-to-the-dockerfile-from-docker-compose/58697363#58697363

Comment: For now I am looking the CLI commands (docker run ...)

Comment: Ok, sorry. I only know the method to pass the variable from the docker-compose file to the docker file or use a shell script to get the system environment variables and pass this as arg to the docker file.

Comment: @Rene After some more readings and tests and failures, I arrived to the conclussion that the best bet seems to be going with a docker-commpose file :-), thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you're using "--env-file <ENV_FILE>" flag or .env file exists in compose directory then, you can directly call values from .env file by using "${ENV_VAR}"
ex:
-env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DB_PW}
https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/